# Why cant we assign char to strings?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, char, initialization

in C++, I noticed if I make a  `string str="kls";`, then I can't write `string s1=str[0];`
I have to instead write:

```
string s1;
s1=str[0];
```

Why so?

Comment: You **can** assign a `char` to a `std::string`; that's exactly what `s1=str[0]` does. What you **can't** do is **construct** a `std::string` from a lone `char`. Don't muddle creating objects with modifying objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the class `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts a single argument of the type `char`. While there is a copy assignment operator that accepts as an argument a single character.

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

You could write

```
std::string s1( 1, str[0] );
```

or (there is used the initializating-list constructor)

```
std::string s1 = { str[0] };
```

or

```
std::string s1 = { str, 0, 1 };
```

Comment: i think part of the question is why `s1=str[0];` works but `string s1=str[0];` not

Comment: What was the motivation behind that decision? Is there a reason to have an assignment that takes a single character but no ctor?

Comment: @Evg I can not say exactly but it seems there can be an ambiguity with the constructor that accepts one argument of an allocator type.